# Vb.net - How to print ""

Tags: vb.net, printing

I know it's probably very silly question so sorry :(, searched forever and I just could not find..

Anyway, Does anyone know how to print the operator **"**

let's say i have the following printing command:

```
MessageBox.Show("Finally!, I can print this operator " ")
```

The problem is that is prints me **Finally!, I can print this operator**

Instead of **Finally!, I can print this operator  "**

Thanks YOU for the help!

Comment: inside a quoted string 2 x " make a quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 solutions :

```
MessageBox.Show("Finally!, I can print this operator "" ")

MessageBox.Show("Finally!, I can print this operator " & Chr(34))
```

In general way the double quote must be doubled to make valid VB string.

Comment: Four spaces for a code indent.  Only use the greater than sign > for quoting other sources.